# Select only not null columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
--------------------
A       null    null
B       null    1
C       null    2

select sum(colB) as sumB, sum(colC) as sumC 
from table
```

I want something like this:

```
SumC
--------
3
```

I don't want sumB to appear in my output if it has only null values in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select sum(isnull(colC,0)) as sumC from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
if exists ( select * from ( select sum(colB) as sumB,sum(colC) as sumC from table) as d where d.sumB is null)

 select sum(colC) as sumC from table
else 
select sum(colB) as sumB,sum(colC) as sumC from table
```